# Is there a way to get Folder object from ListItem one?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, caml, sharepoint-clientobject

I'm trying to get Folder object by its path in SharePoint 2010 client application using Client Side Object Model (.Net 4.0).

I need to check whether folder described by 'folderPath' variable exists in the library and then get the Folder object for further operations. To enhance performance, I chose to use CAML query to filter the list.

My code:

```
IEnumerable<List> library = this.clientContext.LoadQuery(
    this.clientContext.Web.Lists.Where(p => p.Title == this.documentLibrary));
this.clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
List libraryList = library.FirstOrDefault();
//code to handle libraryList == null

CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml =
   "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\">" +
       "<Query>" +
           "<Where>" +
               "<And>" +
                   "<Eq>" +
                      "<FieldRef Name=\"FSObjType\"/>" +
                      "<Value Type=\"Integer\">1</Value>" +
                   "</Eq>" +
                   "<Eq>" +
                      "<FieldRef Name=\"FileRef\" />" +
                      "<Value Type=\"Text\">" + folderPath + "</Value>" +
                   "</Eq>" +
               "</And>" +
           "</Where>" +
       "</Query>" +
   "</View>";

ListItemCollection items = libraryList.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(items);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

To this point everything is OK. But I don't have any idea how get the 'Folder' object from an item. I tried to do it in this way:

```
Folder folder = items.FirtsOrDefault().Folder;
clientContext.Load(folder);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

and that way (used instead of last three lines from first code snippet):

```
ListItemCollection items = libraryList.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(items, collection => collection.Include(item => item.Folder));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

But in both cases I got an Exception:

1st: 'Field or property 'Folder' does not exist.'

2nd: 'Column 'Folder' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.'

Is there a way to do it? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It actually depends on which version of SharePoint is used.

### SharePoint 2013

In SharePoint 2013 CSOM [ListItem.Folder property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.folder%28v=office.15%29.aspx) gets a folder object that is associated with a folder item.

### SharePoint 2010

In SharePoint 2010 CSOM Folder property is **not** exposed for [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem%28v=office.15%29.aspx) object.

The following method could be used for retrieving `Folder` associated with `ListItem`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get Parent Folder for List Item
/// </summary>
/// <param name="listItem"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static Folder GetListItemFolder(ListItem listItem)
{
    var folderUrl = (string)listItem["FileDirRef"];
    var parentFolder = listItem.ParentList.ParentWeb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);
    listItem.Context.Load(parentFolder);
    listItem.Context.ExecuteQuery();
    return parentFolder;
}
```

Example:

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(webUrl))
{
      var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
      var items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
      context.Load(items);
      context.ExecuteQuery();


      foreach (var item in items)
      {
         var folder = GetListItemFolder(item); //get Folder
         Console.WriteLine(folder.Name);
      }
}
```

Comment: I was using wrong dll versions to work with SP 2010. It should be v14.0.0.0 instead of v15.0.0.0, because `ListItem.Folder` property is supported in SP 2013 and not in 2010.